# With what tools could I make a video like this?

Tags: animation

I have not much experience with video making and I am looking for simplest softwares to make a video like this.
Since you are an expert, which tools do you think have been used?

Video:

Features:

- Animation effects
- Website screenshot (there are not actual screenshot but are re-design to highlight only important feature)
- Illustrations (Where I can found lots of illustration to buy/download) ?

Comment: There are lots of different software packages that could have been used, and trying to guess which one would merely be speculation, and really of no use to you or anyone; knowing what tool was used won't make you able to use it. Perhaps do a bit more research about animation software and if you have any specific questions come back and ask them.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have something to start with.

Comment: Try this one: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=animation+software&s=d&iie=1

Answer (score 0):

I've made many infographic videos similar to this. The workflow is quite simple:

- Write the script about what's going to happen.
- Create the illustrations that are supposed to be seen using Adobe Illustrator.
- Import the Illustrations in After-Effects (as Paths, NOT as pixels, like .png or 
  .jpg!)
- Animate the illustrations and  separate file for each shot.
- Edit everything in Adobe Premiere, add sounds there (or in After-Effects, if you like).

And that's it. The hard part is knowing how to do every single step, which will take weeks or months of practice and dedication to learning the craft.

The easier way would be to buy Illustrations online, like from mr. Horse, BUT:
You will still have to animate the illustrations on your own, which is the hardest part of them all!

If you're not familiar with After-Effects, I don't advice you to spend money on assets that you can't animate. That would be wasted money.